# IIS shows 500 Internal server error on everything

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, plesk

I have a shared Windows hosting account with IIS7.5 and Plesk 10.4 .

Now, when I try to visit every page, an `aspx` page, some `php` pages, or even a `jpg` file, it shows This error:

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

This is last lines of log file: (which plesk shows for me)

> - 2012-03-01 18:25:59 W3SVC100 H105 208.67.23.51 GET /15iya/31.jpg - 80
> - 109.162.226.165 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/535.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/16.0.912.63+Safari/535.7 *jsuid=1735775291;+*_cfduid=dcb02ca5c638c5a33cf10003ae6ac2c561326405625;+_*utma=117785567.65259312.1326369096.1330372520.1330376628.15;+*_utmz=117785567.1327165762.11.5.utmcsr=2barnamenevis.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
> - ghiasi.net 500 19 13 1380 627 531  2012-03-01 18:26:13 W3SVC100 H105 208.67.23.51 GET / - 80 - 109.162.226.165 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/535.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/16.0.912.63+Safari/535.7 *jsuid=1735775291;+*_cfduid=dcb02ca5c638c5a33cf10003ae6ac2c561326405625;+_*utma=117785567.65259312.1326369096.1330372520.1330376628.15;+*_utmz=117785567.1327165762.11.5.utmcsr=2barnamenevis.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
> - ghiasi.net 500 19 13 1380 615 515

Comment: see the setting application-pool for iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try check with your asp.net version enable properly in plesk

https://www.motherhost.com/help/plesk-windows-hosting/iis-shows-500-internal-server-error-on-everything/

To configure ASP.NET Settings for a site:

```
If you are subscribed to several hosting packages and have access to several webspaces associated with your account, in the Subscription menu at the top of the screen, select the required webspace.
Go to the Websites & Domains tab and click your website's domain name.
Click ASP.NET Settings.
Set up the strings that determine database connection data for ASP.NET applications that use databases. This option is available only for ASP.NET 2.0.x.

When you open the ASP.NET configuration screen for the first time, sample connection parameters with common constructions are displayed. You can delete them and specify your own strings.
    To add a string, enter the required data into the Name and Connection Parameters input fields and click next to them.
    To remove a string, click next to it.
Set up custom error messages that will be returned by ASP.NET applications in the Custom Error Settings field:
    To set the custom error messages mode, select an appropriate option from the Custom error mode menu:
        On - custom error messages are enabled.
        Off - custom error messages are disabled and detailed errors are to be shown.
        RemoteOnly - custom error messages are displayed only to remote clients, and ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host users.
    To add a new custom error message (which will be applied unless the Off mode was selected), enter the values in the Status Code and Redirect URL fields, and click .
        Status Code defines the HTTP status code resulting in redirection to the error page.
        Redirect URL defines the web address of the error page presenting information about the error to the client.

    Due to possible conflicts, you cannot add a new custom error message with an error code that already exists, but you can redefine the URL for the existing code.
    To remove a custom error message from the list, click next to it.
Configure compilation settings in the Compilation and Debugging field:
    To determine the programming language to be used as default in dynamic compilation files, choose an entry from Default web page language list.
    To enable compiling retail binaries, leave the Switch on debugging checkbox empty.
    To enable compiling debug binaries, select the Switch on debugging checkbox. In this case, the source code fragments containing error will be shown in a diagnostic page message.

    Note. When running applications in debug mode, a memory and/or performance overhead occurs. It is recommended to use debugging when testing an application and to disable it before deploying the application into production scenario.
Configure encoding settings for ASP.NET applications in the Globalization Settings section:
    To set an adopted encoding of all incoming requests, enter an encoding value into the Request encoding field (default is utf-8).
    To set an adopted encoding of all responses, enter an encoding value into the Response encoding field (default is utf-8).
    To set an encoding which must be used by default for parsing of .aspx, .asmx, and .asax files, enter an encoding value into the File encoding field (default is Windows-1252).
    To set a culture which must be used by default for processing incoming web requests, select an appropriate item from the Culture list.
    To set a culture which must be used by default when processing searches for a locale-dependent resource, select an appropriate item from the UI Culture list.
Set a code access security trust level for ASP.NET applications in the Code Access Security field.

CAS trust level is a security zone to which applications execution is assigned, defining what server resources the applications will have access to.

Important: When an assembly is assigned a trust level that is too low, it does not function correctly. For more information on the permissions levels see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/dnnetsec/html/THCMCh09.asp?frame=true#c09618429_010.
Enable the usage of the auxiliary scripts in the Script Library Settings field. Specifying the script library settings is necessary if the validation web controls are used on your web site. This option is available only for ASP.NET 1.1.x.
    If you need to use auxiliary scripts (specifically, scripts implementing objects for validating input data), provide the settings for .NET framework script library. To do so, enter the path beginning with the domain root directory preceded by the forward slash into the Path to Microsoft script library field, or click the folder icon next to the Path to Microsoft script library field and browse for the required location.
    To initiate the auto-installation of files containing the scripts to the specified location, select the Install checkbox. If the files already exist there, they will be rewritten.
Set client session parameters in the Session Settings field:
    To set up the default authentication mode for applications, select an appropriate item from the Authentication mode list. Windows authentication mode should be selected if any form of IIS authentication is used.
    To set up time that a session can remain idle, type the number of minutes into the Session timeout box.
Click OK to apply all changes.
```

[windows hosting india](https://www.motherhost.com/hosting/windows-web-hosting/)